# Can't find the recorded file after I've stopped recording

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediarecorder

I'm making a simple app that records sound as long as the imagebutton is touched and held, but after I'm done recording, I can't find the file on my android device.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaRecorder recorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //AUDIO RECORDER
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.reset();       
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(externalStoragePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }
    else
    {
        String storagePath = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/easyvoicenotepad/test.3gp");
    }

    //IMAGE BUTTON ONTOUCHLISTENER
    final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
    recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                    recorder = null;
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
} //END OF ONCREATE
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Comment: do you have this folder already created "easyvoicenotepad"

Comment: check my answer and try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create you directory first, add something like this in onCreate method

```
 boolean exists = false;
 File createdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/easyvoicenotepad");
 File createdir2 = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/easyvoicenotepad");
    if (createdir.exists()) {       
    exists = true;
    }
    else {
        createdir.mkdir();
    }
    if (createdir2.exists()) {      
    exists = true;
    }
    else {
        createdir.mkdir();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the device connected to a computer, and are searching for the file on there, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device. I've found files you create during development don't always show up right away, though they do indeed exist.

Add a quick check to ensure the file does exist on external storage after you write it if you suspect it does not for whatever reason.